# Jquery - return this.optional(element) plus my date sanity check is not returning correctly

Tags: jquery, function, validation

I have the following JQuery date sanity Validator code:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("datesanity", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || function(){
        var myDate = value.split('/');
        var subDay = myDate[0];
        var subMonth = myDate[1]-1;
        var subYear = myDate[2];
        // this will "correct" any out of range input
        var subDate = new Date(subYear, subMonth, subDay);
        var calcDay = subDate.getDate();
        var calcMonth = subDate.getMonth();
        var calcYear = subDate.getFullYear();
        // this checks to see if any of the submitted input was out of range
        // comment this out to ignore the discrepancy if you want to set a "corrected" value below
        if (calcDay == subDay && calcMonth == subMonth && calcYear == subYear) {
            return true;
            }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    };
});
```

The original addMethod simply ran my code without the 'return this.optional(element)' and the function.
The code date sanity checks a treat but I needed to only validate when the field was populated.
Looking at many examples it looked like adding the 'return this.optional(element)' was the clean answer. 
I just can't get it to return a false status when you input a duff date.

Comment: If `this.optional(element)` returns `false`, then you're returning the anonymous function itself instead of calling it and returning its result.

Comment: OK. I understand the theory of your reply. Can you help me transpose this into a working fix. I can't find an example anywhere to base my modifications on and get a working result.

Comment: I did try splitting the function out and calling a named function instead but this ALWAYS failed whereas this ALWAYS passed validation (the function code is not being excecuted))

Comment: I would advise you reimplement that around a named function, but don't forget to pass it the `value` argument since it uses it.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to work:

```
function datesanity(value){
    var myDate = value.split('/');
    var subDay = myDate[0];
    var subMonth = myDate[1]-1;
    var subYear = myDate[2];
    // this will "correct" any out of range input
    var subDate = new Date(subYear, subMonth, subDay);
    var calcDay = subDate.getDate();
    var calcMonth = subDate.getMonth();
    var calcYear = subDate.getFullYear();
    // this checks to see if any of the submitted input was out of range
    // comment this out to ignore the discrepancy if you want to set a "corrected" value below
    if (calcDay == subDay && calcMonth == subMonth && calcYear == subYear) {
        return true;
        }
    else {
        return false;
    }
};

jQuery.validator.addMethod("datesanity", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || datesanity(value);
});
```

I was really hoping to keep the code cleaner and have the addmethod as a single entry rather than splitting it into a separate function that is then called. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, but in the mean time I have a working solution, so all is good.

Kind regards

Comment: For what it's worth, you can define an anonymous function and call it at the same time. The resulting syntax, however, would arguably not make the code "cleaner".

Comment: You can use `return calcDay == subDay && calcMonth == subMonth && calcYear == subYear;`